# How to add a column to a table based on information found in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to be able to add a column to a table, but I would need this new column to take in values of other columns in the table.  Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE grocery_price (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price FLOAT);

INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(1, 'Bananas', 1.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(2, 'Peanut Butter', 1.00);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(3, 'Dark Chocolate Bars', 1.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(4, 'Ice cream', 2.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(5, 'Cherries', 0.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(6, 'Chocolate syrup', 1.25);

SELECT * FROM grocery_price

CREATE TABLE Grocery (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, quantity INTEGER, aisle INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Grocery VALUES(1, 'Bananas', 4, 7);
INSERT INTO Grocery VALUES(2, 'Peanut Butter', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Grocery VALUES(3, 'Dark Chocolate Bars', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Grocery VALUES(4, 'Ice cream', 1, 12);
INSERT INTO Grocery VALUES(5, 'Cherries', 6, 2);
INSERT INTO Grocery VALUES(6, 'Chocolate syrup', 1, 4);

SELECT * FROM Grocery
```

I want to create a new column in Grocery called total price that would take the values found in grocery_price.price and Grocery.quantity and multiply them together.  Can I do this without having to convert the values from one column to another? Thanks.

Comment: This is doable by adding a col using Alter command first then update that col by joining both these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Add the new column to the table.

```
alter TABLE Grocery add totalPrice FLOAT;
```

Update the table by creating a join of both the tables and setting the total price to the product of quantity and price.

```
UPDATE Grocery gr
INNER JOIN grocery_price gp ON gr.id = gp.id 
SET gr.totalPrice = CAST(gr.quantity as float) * gp.price;
```

Comment: Add some small explanation your answer, This will helpful to OP and other's to get helped.

Comment: Sure @Balagurunathan. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a computed column or just populate the `total` column as a one time activity?

For a one time activity after creating the column, you can just update it:

```
 Update Grocery
 Set total = cast(g.quantity as float)*p.price
 From grocery g
 Inner join grocery_price p
 On g.name = p.name...
```

Looks like you do not have a common reference column in `grocery_price` table...

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time activity you can execute an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Grocery tb_gr
INNER JOIN grocery_price tb_gp ON tb_gr.id = tb_gp.id 
SET tb_gr.totalPrice = tb_gr.quantity * tb_gp.price;
```

If the values of the Table will be periodically refreshed you can create a view on this table and  execute the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pick more meaningful names for your tables and normalize them (don't duplicate data when possible). Also link tables by having foreign keys. After doing these things your sql will look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE product (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price FLOAT);

INSERT INTO product VALUES(1, 'Bananas', 1.50);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(2, 'Peanut Butter', 1.00);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(3, 'Dark Chocolate Bars', 1.50);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(4, 'Ice cream', 2.50);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(5, 'Cherries', 0.50);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(6, 'Chocolate syrup', 1.25);

SELECT * FROM product;

CREATE TABLE product_inventory (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        product_id INTEGER REFERENCES product (id),
        quantity INTEGER,
        aisle INTEGER,
        total_price FLOAT);

INSERT INTO product_inventory VALUES(1, 1, 4, 7);
INSERT INTO product_inventory VALUES(2, 2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO product_inventory VALUES(3, 3, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO product_inventory VALUES(4, 4, 1, 12);
INSERT INTO product_inventory VALUES(5, 5, 6, 2);
INSERT INTO product_inventory VALUES(6, 6, 1, 4);

update product_inventory as pi1 set total_price = (select p.price * pi.quantity as total from product p join product_inventory pi on p.id = pi.product_
id where p.id = pi1.id );

SELECT * FROM product_inventory;
```

The update statement is setting the total_price field in the product_inventory table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select g.id, g.name, g.quantity, g.aisle, (g.quantity*gp.price) AS total_price 
from grocery g left join grocery_price gp 
on g.id=gp.id;
```

Comment: Add some little explanation to understand what is your answer does.

Answer (score 0):

### You should not do this

Yes, you *could* create a new column and update it to contain the information you want, but a far better approach would be to leave independent data *stay* independent.

As it is, your data isn't even independent, since you're repeating the name. So drop that column from your second table.

### Use a view

Then, if you need to present all information in a single table, use a view.

```
CREATE VIEW groceries_with_totals
AS
SELECT
   gp.id,
   gp.name,
   gp.price,
   g.quantity,
   g.quantity * gp.price AS total_price,
   g.aisle
FROM grocery_price gp
JOIN grocery g ON gp.id = g.id;
```

I'm assuming here that `grocery_price.id` references `grocery.id`; you should add a foreign key constraint reflecting that relation.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use an update/view as others have mentioned .Just an alternate would be this :

```
  select g.id,g.name,g.quantity,g.aisle,price*quantity as total_price 
  into #temp
  from grocery_price p join grocery g 
  on p.id=g.id;

  drop table grocery;

  select * into grocery from #temp;
```